# Transcribing a baptism from 1704 in Heinebach

Tags: palaeography, transcriptions, german-language, kurrent, german

I'm trying to read a baptism entry from 1704 in Heinebach.  The priest's handwriting is pretty terrible, however.  I could use assistance in finishing this transcription.

[image]

```
den 23 xembr ist Wilhelm Schwetzer dar [?] [?] [?]
Joh. Conrad [?] Schweizer [?] von Weiterode gegeben
[eodem?] die [pitt?] aus Georg Andermens [?] tochter [?] Joh [?]
Martha Elisabeth [?]mutter [?] [?] ~~
```

Here is the entire page for context: [image]